# Golang exec.Command Defer Path Lookup

Tags: go, environment-variables

I want to set a custom `PATH` environment variable for a command created by `exec.Command`. I want the command's executable to be found off of the custom `PATH` I provide, rather than the operating system's `PATH`.  When you run `exec.Command(executable, arg1, arg2)` it performs a lookup of the executable at that time using the currently available `PATH`.

Is there a way to either:

1. Use `os.Setenv` so that it's only available to the current goroutine
2. Defer the executable's `PATH` lookup until after the environment is set?
3. Another way to override how the executable's lookup is performed?

Otherwise it seems like I'll need to wrap all of the `exec.Command` calls in a mutex to temporarily set the PATH environment variable and then reset it back to it's original value, which seems messy and unideal.

Comment: Why not provide the full path to the executable?

Comment: Neither the executable nor the path are static. They could be different for  each command. I want to avoid hardcoding logic if possible. If i have an executable "xyz" I don't want to have to perform my own checks to see if I need to override the path in the command

Comment: You can prepend your new entries to `PATH`, but the environment is used for the whole process.  If you don't want to do that, then your best bet is probably to keep your own cache of programs and their paths, and update it as needed by searching your custom `PATH`.

Comment: Thanks, yea I figured I would have to do something like that. Was hoping there was a better way

Comment: Questions that begin with "I want to" without any explanation for why you want to do whatever is requested often indicate a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). @aarbor

Comment: Followup to my previous comment: Do you want the new process to inherit your custom `PATH` value? If not why not? I've been programming  on Unix for four decades and have never needed to do what you are asking; nor have I seen this question before now. That doesn't, obviously, mean what you want to do is invalid but it does make me wonder about the phrasing of your question and whether more context would allow the S.O. community to provide better advice.

Comment: @KurtisRader the new process does inherit the path. `cmd.Env = [..., "PATH=/my/custom/path:/other/entries"]` The problem is that this only takes effect after the command starts, not when cmd.Path is initially resolved

Comment: @KurtisRader i can't explain the system in a SO comment, but it's analogous to a plugin system where sometimes we use a system-installed binary (from the path), and other times we use a newer downloaded version from our application in a local cache directory and want to use that instead, depending on context. Are you saying you have never ran a command `PATH=/x/y/z my-command` or overridden the env from command line to override default behavior?

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the code for `exec.Command()`, the absolute path to the executable is [computed right away](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.6:src/os/exec/exec.go;l=418-419) :

```
func Command(name string, arg ...string) *Cmd {
    ...
    if filepath.Base(name) == name {
        lp, err := LookPath(name)
```

and `LookPath()` [relies on the global `os.Getenv("PATH")`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.6:src/os/exec/lp_unix.go;l=64).

The `PATH` lookup is not performed if you provide the full path to the executable though -- as one would expect.

---

One (bad IMHO) way would be to set `PATH` before calling exec.Command() and resstore it afterwards, but this could break many things if several commands are run concurrently. You may use a mutex to protect your own code, but you would have to trust all the external libraries you use to also *not* rely on `PATH` (for example: to never call external commands in goroutines without you knowing).

---

A more reliable way is to rewrite your own version of LookPath(), so that you can use a custom (and local only to your goroutine) PATH value instead of `os.Getenv("PATH")`.
You can then call `cmd.Command(abspath, ...)`, which will not rely on `PATH` anymore.

Depending on the platform(s) you intend to run on, you may start by copying:

- the unix (linux + macOS) version: [`lp_unix.go`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.6:src/os/exec/lp_unix.go;l=52)
- the windows version: [`lp_windows.go`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.6:src/os/exec/lp_windows.go;l=65)
  (TIL: exe lookup on windows also relies on the `PATHEXT` and `NoDefaultCurrentDirectoryInExePath` environment variables)
- the plan9 version ? : [`lp_plan9.go`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.6:src/os/exec/lp_plan9.go;l=38)
- the wasm version just returns an error: [`lp_wasm.go`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.6:src/os/exec/lp_wasm.go;l=20)

note that, although duplicating code is certainly not a good way to proceed *in general*, exe lookup is a very (very very) stable feature and is unlikely to change anytime soon.

Comment: Your answer isn't awful but I think the original question doesn't make much sense without more context. Thus, any attempt to answer it is premature without more context. Also, you can't override the `LookPath()` function used by `Command()`. Which means your answer is ambiguous unless you meant the O.P. should explicitly convert their bare command to an absolute path before calling `exec.Command()`. So I won't upvote your answer and hope no one else does so. See my comments to the question.

Comment: @KurtisRader: I meant: if you run `MyLookPath()` before calling `exec.Command(...)`, you can have your own logic to turn a single word (e.g: `python` or `ruby`) into an absolute path (depending on some parameter: `/usr/bin/python` or `/home/user/.pyenv/python3.12/bin/python`). Once you have an absolute path, there isn't a lookup anymore, you can call `exec.Command(abspath)` just fine.

Comment: you suggested in another comment to set `PATH=...` explicitly on the resulting `exec.Cmd` object, to which I agree ; I actually first checked whether setting `PATH=...` in the `Cmd.Env` field before calling `Run()` or `Start()` wouldn't do the job, and I think I hit the same behavior as the OP: the command name actually gets resolved as soon as you call `exec.Command(...)`, before you have a chance to alter `PATH`. My blind but educated guess is that the OP is trying to handle that initial part.

Comment: Sigh. Neither your original, nor modified, answer references a `MyLookPath()` function. You seem to be suggesting the O.P. simply convert their bare command to an absolute path. Which they stated they did not want to do in their reply to the first comment to their question. So I'm going to downvote your answer since it isn't helpful.

Comment: Well, in linux the quickest workaround is to run a tool through `env`... So using `exec.Command("env", "foobar", "-args")`. Not nice, but it works and it doesn't break the caller process environment.